# Package shell script as RPM

Tags: rpm-spec

I would like to package a shell script to be installed via an RPM. This is my [code repo](https://github.com/kevin-olbrich/k2update/tree/master/rpm), and this is [my build at COPR](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/kolbrich/k2update/builds/).

#### SPEC file

For reference here's my SPEC file:

```
Name:       {{{ git_name }}}
Version:    {{{ git_version }}}
Release:    1%{?dist}
Summary:    k2update

License:    GPLv2+
URL:        https://someurl.org
VCS:        {{{ git_vcs }}}

Source:     {{{ git_pack }}}

%description
k2update

%prep
{{{ git_setup_macro }}}
%setup

%changelog
{{{ git_changelog }}}

%install
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/sbin
install -m755 k2update $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/sbin/k2update
install -m755 k2update_real $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/sbin/k2update_real

%files
k2update
k2update_real
```

Most probably this is just an error in the SPEC file I missed?

#### Copr logs

For reference here's the log from the Copr build server:

```
Warning: Permanently added '172.25.84.142' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Running: /usr/bin/copr-rpmbuild --verbose --drop-resultdir --srpm --build-id 779046 --detached
Version: 0.19
Task:
{'build_id': 779046,
 'chroot': None,
 'project_name': 'k2update',
 'project_owner': 'kolbrich',
 'source_json': {'clone_url': 'https://github.com/kevin-olbrich/k2update.git',
                 'committish': 'master',
                 'spec': 'k2update.spec',
                 'srpm_build_method': 'rpkg',
                 'subdirectory': '',
                 'type': 'git'},
 'source_type': 8,
 'task_id': '779046'}

Running: git clone https://github.com/kevin-olbrich/k2update.git /tmp/tmpi8cvwhdn/k2update --depth 500 --no-single-branch

cmd: ['git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/kevin-olbrich/k2update.git', '/tmp/tmpi8cvwhdn/k2update', '--depth', '500', '--no-single-branch']
cwd: .
rc: 0
stdout: 
stderr: Cloning into '/tmp/tmpi8cvwhdn/k2update'...

Running: git checkout master

cmd: ['git', 'checkout', 'master']
cwd: /tmp/tmpi8cvwhdn/k2update
rc: 0
stdout: Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
stderr: Already on 'master'

Running: rpkg -C /etc/rpkg.conf srpm --outdir /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/results/tmpdc5xcgui --spec /tmp/tmpi8cvwhdn/k2update/k2update.spec

cmd: ['rpkg', '-C', '/etc/rpkg.conf', 'srpm', '--outdir', '/var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/results/tmpdc5xcgui', '--spec', '/tmp/tmpi8cvwhdn/k2update/k2update.spec']
cwd: /tmp/tmpi8cvwhdn/k2update
rc: 0
stdout: git_pack: Wrote: /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/results/tmpdc5xcgui/k2update-0.0.git.48.e2e8b22.tar.gz
Wrote: /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/results/tmpdc5xcgui/k2update.spec
Wrote: /var/lib/copr-rpmbuild/results/tmpdc5xcgui/k2update-0.0.git.48.e2e8b22-1.fc28.src.rpm
stderr: 

Output: ['k2update.spec', 'k2update-0.0.git.48.e2e8b22-1.fc28.src.rpm', 'k2update-0.0.git.48.e2e8b22.tar.gz']
```

Comment: gihub gives me a 404

Comment: Verify what you have w/ the hello world SPEC - https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_GNU_Hello_RPM_package. Also can you build this locally? The logs don't show where it's failing either, which is extremely odd.

Comment: Your code is here: https://github.com/kevin-olbrich/k2update/blob/master/k2update.spec

Comment: The Q has a 404 URL to the git repo, but the build job looks correct based on the logs I pasted into the Q.

Comment: Useful resources for Copr - https://docs.pagure.org/copr.copr/user_documentation.html#faq.

Comment: Thank you very much. After submit of my post, I relocated the files inside the repo. With the COPR FAQ I was able to fix my spec file. Error was Source0 and Source1 and the reference under %install.